# Messaging endpoint is not updating in Bot Channels Registration nor Bot Channels Registration is deleting

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

Messaging endpoint is not updating, there are a lot of console errors saying "Failed patching resource entity", "Failed refreshing resource entity", I tried deleting the bot channel registration, delete is also not working it says "Failed to delete bot".

Just to test I created a new bot channels registration and it worked fine, but this one isn't, please help on how to fix this issue, I need to update the settings or at least delete the one that is not working.

[image: Issue Screenshot 1]

[image: Issue Screenshot 2]

[image: Issue Screenshot 3]

Comment: We are currently working on a fix for this

Comment: I am able to update the Messaging endpoint now, however, I didn't test whether delete is working fine for the bot channels registration